# Angular 17 and Leaflet Heatmap work localhost:4200 but dont work on Xampp ip

Tags: angular, leaflet

I use angular 17.0.3 and leaflet ^1.9.4, leaflet.heat ^0.2.0 in my project.
It work on localhost but when i start xampp and look my ip, it give error.

Step by step;

**package.json =>**
`... "leaflet": "^1.9.4", "leaflet.heat": "^0.2.0", ...`

**angular.json =>**
 `"styles": [ ... "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css", ...],`

`"scripts": [... "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js", ...]`

**component =>**

`
initHeatMap() {

```
let totalCoords :any[]= [] 

const map = L.map('map6162').setView([ 39.75, 30.75], 8);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

this.centerKoords.forEach(coord => {
  //@ts-ignore
  const coordinate = coord.coords
  totalCoords.push([coordinate[1],coordinate[0], 250])
});
//@ts-ignore
L.heatLayer(totalCoords).addTo(map);
```

}`

i have polygons so i create a variable => centerKoords
example => centerKoords = [{id: 0, coords: [0,0]}, {id: 1, coords: [0,1]}]

after i create totalCoords and take center coords in here with 250.
i add totalCoords in heatLayer.

i dont create interfaces so i use //@ts-ignore.

---

all codes are work on my localhost. But when i take build (i use ng build or ng build --configuration=production) and i look my xampp ip it doesnt work.
It say =>
`ERROR TypeError: L7.heatLayer is not a function`

---

i take same error for markercluster and i do this =>

`
...
import * as L1 from 'leaflet.markercluster';
...

export class TestCesComponent implements OnInit {
....
// @ts-ignore
markers = new L1.MarkerClusterGroup()

after i create a function and i write;
marker.addTo(this.markers)
`
but i cant solve heatmap problem.

I'm sorry for my bad English skill, thanks for helps

My codes work on localhost but not work when i test on Xampp Ip